# UIButton touch up inside event, bounds change?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, bounds, uievent

So, I discovered an interesting behavior of `UIButton` after wasting a couple of hours late last night. I probably have come across this in the past but can't recall. I couldn't find an explanation for this behavior thus far, so please enlighten me if you have any info on this:

Create an instance of `UIButton`, then set its action for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. Now, in your running app, press on the button and hold down, move away from the button and notice how it seems like the bounds changed when moving/dragging your finger. The touch is recognized quite some distance from the button's original frame, bounds.

This caused quite some problems in my app where I implemented code using locationInView: to determine the indexPath of the `UITableViewCell` that is the superview of the button.

My two alternative solutions for determining the indexPath are:

1. Use the buttons superview's
   superview, which is the
   `UITableViewCell`, together with
   UITableView's `indexPathForCell`:
   method.
2. Rather use `UIControlEventTouchDown`
   when specifying my button action.

Hope someone finds this helpful or can contribute to a solution for the problem.

Comment: I think this is a feature not a bug. I think this is done to be more touch friendly.

Comment: Yes, my thought also... the documentation leaves us guessing though...

Answer (score 1):

You could use touchesBegan:withEvent.

Comment: Yes, but then you need to subclass each button you ever use.

Comment: No, you can use touchesBegan in the view controller.